# run multiple model after grouping and save as columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to run multiple mix effect models on grouped data. Here are the codes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)

dat.tx.a <- mvrnorm(n=250, mu=c(30, 20, 28), 
                    Sigma=matrix(c(25.0, 17.5, 12.3, 
                                   17.5, 25.0, 17.5, 
                                   12.3, 17.5, 25.0), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE))
dat.tx.b <- mvrnorm(n=250, mu=c(30, 20, 22), 
                    Sigma=matrix(c(25.0, 17.5, 12.3, 
                                   17.5, 25.0, 17.5, 
                                   12.3, 17.5, 25.0), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE))
dat <- data.frame(rbind(dat.tx.a, dat.tx.b))
names(dat) = c("measure.1", "measure.2", "measure.3")
dat <- data.frame(subject.id=factor(1:500), tx=rep(c("A", "B"), each=250), dat)
rm(dat.tx.a, dat.tx.b)
dat <- reshape(dat, varying=c("measure.1", "measure.2", "measure.3"), 
               idvar="subject.id", direction="long")

df.model<-dat %>%
           group_by(tx) %>%
           do (model1=lmer(measure~(1|subject.id), data=.)) %>% 
           do (model2=lmer(measure~time+(1|subject.id), data=.))
```

Here is the error message:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("lmerMod", package = "lme4")" to a data.frame
```

The code works if I remove the line that runs model2. It seems that the dataframe only accept one column as a list of models? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since you are using the pipe (`%>%`) what you are actually doing here is passing the output of `do(model1...)` to the statement `do(model2...)`, which is of course not what you intend to do. Instead you could write a function that fits both models and returns a list.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the multiple models to `do()` :

```
df.model<-dat %>%
  group_by(tx) %>%
  do (model1=lmer(measure~(1|subject.id), data=.),
      model2=lmer(measure~time+(1|subject.id), data=.))
```

Also note that in your example you are using the `MASS` package.